# jQuery appends [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, servlets

I have this AJAX function for retrieving XML with the usernames from the Java servlet. I parse the usernames here and send them to the `addToUserList` function, where I append with jQuery. But `[Object HTMLInputElement]` is the only thing which appends to the list. When I run the AJAX function on my browser console the returned XML has a first element which is `[object HTMLInputElement]`, but there are usernames following it.

```
function displayFriendList(){
    $.ajax({
        url : '/getFriendList?userid=' +userid,
        type : "POST",
        dataType: 'xml',
        success : function(data) { 
            $(data).find("friend").each(function () {
                addToUserList($(this).find("username").text());
            });
        },
    })
}
```

Here is the addToUserList function

```
var userList = new Array();

function addToUserList(friend){

    var exists = false;

    for(var i=1; i<userList.length; i++){
        if(userList[i]==friend){
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!exists){

        userList.push(friend);
        $('#userList').append("<a>"+friend+"</a></br>");
```

and a part of the returned xml

```
<data>
<friend><username>[object HTMLInputElement]</username></friend>
<friend><username>asa</username></friend>
<friend><username>asda</username></friend>
<friend><username>cece</username></friend>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for addToUserList?

Comment: Can you post XML snippet of the data structure?

Comment: unrelated issue: arrays start from 0 so `var i=1;` should be `var i=0;` in the `for`.

Comment: also `</br>` should be `<br/>` and finally it works here http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/y3FdT/1/

Answer (score 0):

Do you need key and value in a .each?

```
$(data).find("friend").each(function (k,v) {
                addToUserList($(v).find("username").text());
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var userList = new Array();
```

you re-initialize the user list every time you call the function, this doesn't seem right